# R speed up addition of a constant in a raster file

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster brick, converted from a `netcdf` file of some climate data. The climate data have a temperature variable in Kelvin that I want to convert to Celsius.

The math is simple. The raster brick is called `ncin.brick`. The math is

```
ncin.brick <- ncin.brick - 273.15
```

This works but takes a very long time (like `15` minutes on my Mac).

My suspicion is that this is because the data are mostly on disk and need to be read in to do the math. I tried using

`ncin.brick <- readAll(ncin.brick)`

which reads all the data into memory. The calculation is quicker, but the help manual says not to do this. I also tried wrapping the command in `beginCluster()` and `endCluster()`. It doesn't seem to make much difference although I haven't tried these various techniques with a timing loop to see how much difference they do make.

Am I missing some option for this simple calc to speed it up?

Comment: You should give more info on your `ncin.brick`. How you convert it and what for it is.

Comment: The netcdf file is read in with` ncin.brick <- brick(temp, varname = varToGet)` where temp is the name and path to the netcdf file. For the file I'm working on, the data are daily observations of maximum temperature for 10 years.